Insecure download blocked - Affecting Chrome 124 not 123
A selenium testcase clicks an http download link, and is blocked from downloading in Chrome v124, with UI message 'insecure download blocked'.
I have the following Chrome config set - which worked with Chrome v123. What needs to change so that insecure downloads are not blocked with v124?
service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
options.add_argument('--disable-features=InsecureDownloadWarnings')
options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
            "download.default_directory": testcase_download_directory,
            "download.prompt_for_download": False,
            "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
            "safebrowsing.disable_download_protection": True,
            "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1
            })


This did the trick:
options.add_argument("--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://example.com")
